# Unable to allow IE10 to run scripts

Tags: javascript, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

My IE10 has stopped execution of JavaScript for pages stored locally, infact it does not asks for permission to allow their execution.

I have Windows 8 x64 with IE 10 installed. A few days back whenever I used to open a file which used JavaScript IE10 used to display a message "IE restricted this webpage from running scripts or activex controls" with a button to allow blocked content.

Now, *this dialog doesn't appear at all* and I'm unable to test JavaScript programs in my local machine using IE. (On websites like gmail etc JS simply works).

I have tried changing security setting inside internet options to lowest but no use.

P.S.: On repeatedly clicking reload on realized that permission to allow blocked context dialog appears for fraction of a second and disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing a cumulative security update for IE10 Windows 8 x64 from 
 [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36874)

Don't know why this is related with the issue, but my friend suggested me try to update IE, and on googling I found this update.

I posted it here because when I searched internet for the solution, I was not able to find any case of this type.

Comment: Oh God! My IE is again giving same problems, restarting windows 8 fixed the problem this time.